# ToggleButton isChecked vs isActivated - Android

Tags: android, togglebutton

I'm trying to see what method of the ToggleButton widget is used to check if it is switched to "on" or "off", and I couldn't make out of the reference if it's `isChecked()` or `isActivated()`

What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference become clear from the documentation:

```
public boolean isActivated ()
```

is View method and responsible for providing basic View state. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isActivated%28%29) is clear description of what *activation* is in Android terms.

From the other hand,

```
public boolean isChecked ()
```

is more 'high level' property of another entity - [CompoundButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#isChecked%28%29) and provides it's state - is it ON or OFF.

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question, it's just a link to the javadoc.

Comment: Sometimes javadocs provide best answers. Btw, I'm not able to see Yours answer at all.

Answer (score 4):

[`View.setActivated()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setActivated%28boolean%29) says in the JavaDoc that the activated state has nothing to do with `CheckBox` or `ToggleButton`, but with some kind of selection state that a generic `View` can be in when in a ListView.

The developers even apologize for the confusion:

> Um, yeah, we are deeply sorry about the terminology here

`isActivated()` is also only available on API levels > 11.

`isChecked()` is from `CompoundView`, which `ToggleButton` and `CheckBox` both extend from. This is the state that you want to be checking for. It is available on all API levels.

Comment: They should. I used isActivated and saw it's always false. I'm using switchcompat, there is no documentation about how to check its state.

Answer (score 3):

use `isChecked()` for ON and OFF

```
if (isChecked()) {
        // The toggle is enabled  ON state
    } else {
        // The toggle is disabled  OFF state
    }
```

As i know there is no `isActivated()` method for toggle button, it is for a `view` either it is active or not.